# memset like functionality on lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to modify a very large list while performing a task, and after completion of the task I want to set all the elements of the list to a single value as quickly as possible. In C++ we use memset for this purpose. Is there any way in python to do this job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `memset` only works on arrays of bytes, not any other type of array (let alone lists).

Comment: you can accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: Didn't help my purpose but I got to know about generators a little more(read about them with a hope that it helps). Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are looking for is speed in terms of execution of the program.

> memset() is a very fast version of a relatively simple operation:

[Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to the rescue over here. They are tremendously faster than lists when dealing with large data sets. You can iterate through them only once.

```
# construct a generator:
def fun():
  for i in range(0,3): # Basically construct your list like this
    yield  i

a = fun()

# iterate through generator:
for i in a:
  # do manipulations on i

# create a new generator yielding all same values for your last operation
```

Comment: What if I don't perform manipulations on 'i' in order(like from the first element to the last element in order)? I modify the list elements at random.

Comment: For example, a boolean list 'visited' which stores if i th vertex in a graph is visited while performing depth first search. After performing a dfs operation, I need to set all the elements in the 'visited' list to 'False', so that the list can be used for next dfs operation.

Comment: @TarunSai you can yield anything you want as many times. Make a function then `yield 3`, `yield 'generator'`, `yield True` and those three things would be stored in a sort of super fast list: `[3, 'generator', True]`